# Program wont exit with EOF and wont print if last character is ' [space]'

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am new to C so please forgive my misunderstandings. I am trying to write a simple program that takes a users character input, mutates it, and prints it out in "piglatin"... where the first letter of a word is moved to the end of the word and then an "ay" is appended to the end of the word. Example-> the word "like" becomes ... "ikelay". Here is my program...

```
//pig latin

#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000

void pigify(char chars[], int cnt);
void sortWords(char stream[], int total);
void clearWord(char word[], int j);

int main(){

    int c, i;
    char allChars[MAX];


    i = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        allChars[i] = c;
        ++i;
    } 

    allChars[i] = '\0';

    sortWords(allChars, i);

    return 0;

}



/////////////////
/////////////////
void sortWords(char stream[], int total){

    int i, j, start, end, m;
    char words[total];

    clearWord(words, total);

    i = j = end = m = 0;

    while(stream[i] != '\0'){
        if(stream[i] != '\n' && stream[i] != '\t' && stream[i] != ' '){
            ++i;
            ++j;
        } else if (j > 2){
            end = i;
            for(start = i-j; start <= end; ++start){
                words[m] = stream[start];
                ++m;
            }

            pigify(words, m);
            clearWord(words, m);
            j = m = 0;
        }

    }   

}

/////////////////
/////////////////
void clearWord(char word[], int i){
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j <= i; ++j){
        word[j] = '\0'; 
    }

}



/////////////////
/////////////////
void pigify(char alls[], int cnt){

    int j;
    char pchars[cnt+3];

    j = 0;

    while(alls[j] != '\0'){
        pchars[j] = alls[j];
        ++j;
    }


    if(alls[0] != 'a' && alls[0] != 'e' && alls[0] != 'i' && alls[0] != 'o' &&     alls[0] != 'u'){
        pchars[cnt] = alls[0];
        pchars[cnt+1] = 'a';
        pchars[cnt+2] = 'y';
        pchars[cnt+3] = '\0';
        pchars[0] = ' ';
    }


    printf("\npost pigification --> %s\n", pchars);

}
```

I have been on it for a long time and I can't find where i've made a mistake. I do not care so much about the program, I don't need to convert input to "piglatin" but I would really love to know what I have done wrong!!! Help, advice, and/or pointers would be awesome! thank you

Comment: Note: consider more useful variables names than `j` and `m`.

Answer (score 1):

Writing outside array bounds.  Use `<`

```
char words[total];
clearWord(words, total);

void clearWord(char word[], int i){
    int j;
    // for (j = 0; j <= i; ++j){
    for (j = 0; j < i; ++j){
        word[j] = '\0'; 
    }
}
```

May have other problems too

Comment: thanks for this, certianly a mistake i missed, however the result is the same. It still will only print a single word in the piglatin form,

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    allChars[i] = c;
    ++i;
}
```

With this:

```
while ((allChars[i] = getchar()) != '\n')
    i++;
```

Otherwise, every time you press enter, the loop starts over. Maybe someone else can explain that, but the above code will let your code do what you want it to.

In the future, a function such as `fgets()` may be more suitable for your needs, as you don't have to worry about checking for EOF and such - you just have to strip the newline at the end in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the help but this doesn't work either. It only mutates and prints the first word in the line. Do you have any explanation as to why i can not use EOF in the manner i have it? I am unfamilair with `fgets()`, I am trying to use only what i've learned so far (which is just chapter one of K & R)

Answer (score 0):

With help form @chux and after using some more print statements to find out what is going on, I realized that in the function `sortWords` the variable `i` was not being incremented for the case in which a space '' '' character or a new line or tab character ''\n'' and ''\t'' was reached. After changing the function to this ...

```
void sortWords(char stream[], int total){

int i, j, start, end, m;
char words[total];

clearWord(words, total);

i = j = end = m = 0;

while(stream[i] != '\0'){
    if(stream[i] != '\n' && stream[i] != '\t' && stream[i] != ' '){
        ++i;
        ++j;
    } else if (j > 2){
        end = i;
        for(start = i-j; start <= end; ++start){
            words[m] = stream[start];
            ++m;
        }

        pigify(words, m);
        clearWord(words, m);
        j = m = 0;
        ++i;
    }

}   

}
```

The program works at least somewhat more as expected. The bugs i set out to solve with this question are fixed at least. Still not perfect but i think this was a poorly asked question on my part and should be ended